# count database rows return null instead of 0

Tags: mysql, sql, backend

When I'm trying to count how many likes each user has 
I do like this :

```
SELECT likes.LI_CNT liked_count
FROM `users` 
left outer JOIN (SELECT `user_id`, COUNT(*) LI_CNT
      FROM `likes`
      GROUP BY likes.`user_id`) likes ON users.`user_id` = likes.`user_id`
```

**But** this query return null values for those users who didn't like 
any tweet instead of returning zero!
I tried to use this if statement but it returns the same result (with null values)

```
COUNT(IF(likes.user_id is null, 0, 1))
```

my tables schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tweets` (
  `tweet_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `reply_to_tweet_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `reply_to_user_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `truncated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `media` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `entities` json NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tweet_id`)
)


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `likes` (
  `user_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `tweet_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`tweet_id`)
)


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `handelname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `account_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bio` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `profile_pic` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cover_pic` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `protected` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
)
```

how to get zero instead of null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COUNT(*)` *never* returns `NULL` values.  But `LEFT JOIN` does.  If there is no match, then all columns -- including the count would be `NULL`.

One solution is to just use `COALESCE()` in the outer `SELECT`:

```
COALESCE(LI_CNT, 0) as LI_CNT
```